# lua - check if userdata is nil

Tags: lua, cjson, lua-userdata

I trying to use lua cjson to parse to following json :

```
 {
       "data" : null,
         "message" : "Your session has expired. Please login again.",
           "code" : "390112",
             "success" : false
 }
```

it's parsed to the following map :

```
{ ["message"] = Your session has expired. Please login again.,["success"] = false,["data"] = userdata: (nil),["code"] = 390112,}
```

and i trying to to do something like:

```
if decoded["data"] == nil or decoded["data"] ==userdata(nil)  then
  return 
end
```

is that possible?

(userdata(nil) is not valid expression )

Comment: Your examples don't make sense to me. Please provide a [mcve]. Userdata cannot be nil. userdata an nil are two different types. userdata type values cannot be (de-)serialized by lua-cjson.

Comment: but when i dump the response this is the answer "["data"] = userdata: (nil)"

Comment: use `cjson.null`. It is zero lightuserdata. You can not create it from Lua. Only via C API